# Cannot get predictions of tensorflow DNNClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the code from the MNIST tutorial:

```
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=2,
                                            model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")

classifier.fit(x=np.array(train, dtype = 'float32'),
               y=np.array(y_tr, dtype = 'int64'),
               steps=2000)

accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=np.array(test, dtype = 'float32'),
                                     y=y_test)["auc"]
print('AUC: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))

from tensorflow.contrib.learn import SKCompat
ds_test_ar = np.array(ds_test, dtype = 'float32')

ds_predict_tf = classifier.predict(input_fn = _my_predict_data)
print('Predictions: {}'.format(str(ds_predict_tf)))
```

but at the end I got the following result instead of the predictions:

```
Predictions: <generator object DNNClassifier.predict.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000002CE41101CA8>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you received and saved to `ds_predict_tf` is a generator expression. 
To print it you can do:

```
for i in ds_predict_tf:
    print i
```

or

```
print(list(ds_predict_tf))
```

You can read more about genexpr [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164642/python-print-a-generator-expression).

Comment: Thank you! strange that didn't get your reply until now, found that myself, very sorry for such a simple question!

Answer (score 9):

> The DNNClassifier predict function by default have **as_iterable=True**. Thus, it returns an generator. For getting values of predictions instead of generator, pass **as_iterable=False** in classifier.predict method.

For example,

> `classifier.predict(input_fn = _my_predict_data,as_iterable=False)`

---

---

For understanding more about classifier methods and arguments. Here is a part of documentation for predict method.

From [DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier) documentation:

## Predict

> Args:

- x: features.
- input_fn: Input function. If set, x must be None.
- batch_size: Override default batch size.
- outputs: list of str, name of the output to predict. If None, returns classes.
- ### as_iterable: If True, return an iterable which keeps yielding predictions for each example until inputs are exhausted. Note: The inputs must terminate if you want the iterable to terminate (e.g. be sure to pass num_epochs=1 if you are using something like read_batch_features).

> Returns:

- Numpy array of predicted classes with shape [batch_size] (**or an iterable of predicted classes if as_iterable is True**). Each predicted class is represented by its class index (i.e. integer from 0 to n_classes-1). If outputs is set, returns a dict of predictions.

Comment: `as_iterable` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:-**

```
pred = classifier.fit(x=training_set.data, y=training_set.target, steps=2000).predict(test_set.data)

print ("Predictions:")

print(list(pred))
```

*That's it...*

Answer (score 1):

To be as close as possible to the tutorial use:

```
print('Predictions: {}' .format(list(ds_predict_tf)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the answer is very easy, you need to use the `predictor` as `generator` object:

```
g1 = ds_predict_tf

[g1.__next__() for i in range(100)]
```