# Discord.py printing a invite link

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

I'm having an issue where i try to print a invite link into console, but instead it prints out

```
<generator object Client.create_invite at 0x000001D310A183B8>
<generator object Client.create_invite at 0x000001D310A65410>
```

i am using this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():

    #await client.change_presence(game=Game(name="with humans"))
    print("Logged in as " + client.user.name)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            channel_type = channel.type
            if str(channel_type) == 'text':
                invitelinknew = client.create_invite(destination=channel, xkcd=True, max_uses=100)
                print(str(invitelinknew))
                break
```

i tried changing `print(invitelinknew)` to `print(str(invitelinknew))`, but it didn't change the outcome

EDIT:

New errors when consuming the genrator with `invitelinknew2 = list(invitelinknew)`
and `print(invitelinknew2)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Rasmus/Python/discordbot/botnoggi2.py", line 128, in on_ready
    invitelinknew2 = list(invitelinknew)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2628, in create_invite
    data = yield from self.http.create_invite(destination.id, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 137, in request
    r = yield from self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 555, in __iter__
    resp = yield from self._coro
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 202, in _request
    yield from resp.start(conn, read_until_eof)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 640, in start
    message = yield from httpstream.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 641, in read
    result = yield from super().read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 476, in read
    yield from self._waiter
AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ServerDisconnectedError()>
aiohttp.errors.ServerDisconnectedError
```

Comment: Like the output says, it's a `generator object`. You need to consume the generator. e.g. `list(invitelinknew)` or `set(invitelinknew)` or something else, depending on the type returned.

Comment: Better dupe target - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164642/python-print-a-generator-expression

Comment: How do i know what type the generator is, so i can use the right way to consume it

Comment: Just try doing `print(list(invitelinknew))` first, then print that, depending on what you see you can decide how to consume (besides `list`).

Comment: added new error codes to my question

Comment: Related - https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/529

Comment: Solved my question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.Client.create_invite) `create_invite` is a coroutine and requires the `await` keyword

Change your code to include it such as

```
if channel.type == discord.ChannelType.text:
  invitelinknew = await client.create_invite(destination=channel, xkcd=True, max_uses=100)
  print(invitelinknew.url)
```