# Printing using print(x for x in list) unexpected result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I was working with this code - sys.path is a list andits memebers are strings - but when used the below code, it is showing 
 at 0x00B38C30>, please explain why?

Code :

```
import sys
print(x for x in sys.path)
```

sys.path is this

```
['C:\\Users\\eastwood\\OneDrive\\Python_Work\\Trials', 'C:\\Users\
\eastwood\\OneDrive\\Python_Work\\Trials', 'C:\\Users\\eastwood\\A
ppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip', 'C:\\
Users\\eastwood\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DL
Ls', 'C:\\Users\\eastwood\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Pytho
n37-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\eastwood\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Pyth
on\\Python37-32', 'C:\\Users\\eastwood\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\
Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

And

```
print(x for x in sys.path)
```

gives `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00B38C30>`

```
import sys
print(x for x in sys.path)
```

I was expecting the code to print the members of sys.path list!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: print a generator expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164642/python-print-a-generator-expression)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any thing around the loop it's gonna be a generator, so use:

```
import sys
print([x for x in sys.path])
```