# Parallel network requests:Comparing different approaches

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, pool

I would like to request 100 urls at a time and am currently doing this:

```
responses = list(PoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_PARALLEL).map(
                 lambda xml: requests.post(URL, headers=HEADERS, data={'message': xml}), 
                 xmls))
```

A few questions on this:

1. Is `list` the best way to 'evaluate' the actual generator object/expression? Unless I do `list` I just get something like: `<generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x10ecf9888>`
2. Is `PoolExecutor` used frequently to do parallel network requests in python3, or are there are other methods that are more preferable?
3. What are the differences between `PoolExecutor`, `AsyncIO` and `concurrent.futures` to do something like this?

Comment: I think there are examples in the `AsyncIO` docs that are similar to your example. I would probably use `concurrent.futures` - but at times I've thought it would be worthwhile  getting more proficient with `AsyncIO`.

Comment: Where does `PoolExecutor` come from? _Is list the best way to 'evaluate'..._ That should be covered in the docs, right? If not, I'm sure there is plenty of information out there. _Is PoolExecutor used frequently to do parallel network requests in python3, or are there are other methods that are more preferable?_ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: I forgot to mention that #2 is likely quite subjective. Judging how popular/common a library is can be done to some extent, although it isn't exactly idea. _are there are other methods that are more preferable_ even more so, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

> Is list the best way to 'evaluate' the actual generator
>   object/expression? Unless I do list I just get something like:
>   .result_iterator at
>   0x10ecf9888>

There's a [specific answer in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165222/5675325) which I think addresses your concern.

> Is PoolExecutor used frequently to do parallel network requests in
>   python3, or are there are other methods that are more preferable?

There's other methods, yes, and you can find here in StackOverflow [at least one question giving different examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632520/5675325). Within the answers to that question, there's only one person using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and that's the closest you'll get to `PoolExecutor` there.

> What are the differences between PoolExector, AsyncIO and
>   concurrent.futures to do something like this?

The answer to this question can be found in the book [Using Asyncio in Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1492075337), **Chapter 3. Asyncio Walk-Through**. More precisely, AsyncIO provides an API that is very similar to the API in the concurrent.futures package. This package provides a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and a `ProcessPoolExecutor`. The default is thread-based, but either thread-based or pool-based executors can be used.