# Getting Error: "not enough values to unpack" when returning two outputs using list comprehension with Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The objective is to create a list comprehension that outputted two values.

The for loops look like below

```
paper_href_scopus = []
paper_title = []
for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}):
    paper_href_scopus.append(litag['href'])
    paper_title.append(litag.text)
```

While creating list comprehension as below work without any error

```
[(paper_href_scopus.append(litag['href']), paper_title.append(litag.text)) \
   for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})]
```

Modifying the  list comprehension as below:

```
paper_href_scopus, paper_title = [(litag['href'], litag.text) \
    for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})]
```

resulting an error of :

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

May I know how such an error can be avoided?

Comment: `x, y = zip(*[(litag['href'], litag.text) for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `zip` like,

```
>>> paper_href_scopus, paper_title = zip(*[(litag['href'], litag.text) for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})])
```

Also, no need to create the `list` inside, you can use a `genexpr`, but i don't think it will matter here. Neverthless:

```
>>> paper_href_scopus, paper_title = zip(*((litag['href'], litag.text) for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})))
```

**Note:**

As suggested by [balandongiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6446053/balandongiv), here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164642/python-print-a-generator-expression/5165222#5165222) to `genexpr` usage and another link to official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

Comment: Hi Han, thanks for the input especially the `genexpr`. One request, can you edit your answer and place the following link to genexpr: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165222/6446053. This may help future reader

Comment: @balandongiv Sure :)

Comment: Thanks for the update @han, btw, if have another problem with your proposed solution for some condition, appreciate if you can have a look at the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204196/getting-error-not-enough-values-to-unpack-when-using-list-comprehension-toget