# Getting Error: 'not enough values to unpack' when using list comprehension together with conditional statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

The objective is to create a list comprehension that outputs two values.

The for loops look like below

```
    paper_href_scopus = []
    paper_title = []
    for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}):
        paper_href_scopus.append(litag['href'])
        paper_title.append(litag.text)
```

As suggested by [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63203745/6446053), this can be achieved by

```
    paper_href_scopus, paper_title = zip(*[(litag['href'], litag.text) for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})])
```

However, there is an instances where the `all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})` returns `empty` and the compiler returns an error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Based on the discussion in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474933/list-comprehension-with-if-statement), it seems the above code can be modified as

```
     paper_href_scopus, paper_title = zip(
                        *((litag['href'], litag.text) for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}) \
                          if all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}
                          ))
```

But still, the compiler returns an error

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Nevertheless, the following code works despite the fact that on some occasions the  `all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})` returns `empty`

```
    [(paper_href_scopus.append(litag['href']), paper_title.append(litag.text)) \
                     for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})]
```

But, I would like to avoid using append as there is requirement to initialize  `paper_href_scopus=[]` and `paper_title=[]` beforehand.

May I know, what can I do to fix the code?

```
    paper_href_scopus, paper_title = zip(
                        *((litag['href'], litag.text) for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}) \
                          if all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}
                          ))
```

Comment: Can you add minimal code to reproduce?

Comment: I would suggest, you assign this to a name like `a_tds = all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})` then pass that to `zip` only if it's not empty.

Comment: Thanks @han, I thinks this will lead to extra line of code, but I think the number of execution is still the same either ways. I believe you are proposing something like `a_tds = all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})
                if a_tds:
                    paper_href_scopus, paper_title = zip(
                        *[(litag['href'], litag.text) for litag in a_tds])`

Comment: Yes. Don't worry about lines. "Lines are free, clarity is priceless" and in this case required :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the version with the `if` is basically equivalent to:

```
tmp = []
for litag in all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}):
    if all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'}):
        tmp.append((litag['href'], litag.text))

paper_href_scopus, paper_title = zip(*tmp)
```

which, if your document has 100 matching elements, it does 101 searches.

Here's my proposal: forget about the `zip`. Instead, split out the code a bit:

```
litags = all_td.find_all('a', {'class': 'ddmDocTitle'})
paper_href_scopus = [litag['href'] for litag in litags]
paper_title = [litag.text for litag in litags]
```

Comment: While this suggestion improve overall readability, but I would like to keep the number of lines minimal as possible. But somehow, this suggestion omit the use of 'zip' which I think may improved the overall execution speed maybe. But I think this approach will required further tweak to handle  if 'litgas' returns empty.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because my suggestion should handle the empty case just fine. (And I don't know why you would want to reduce the number of lines to the extent that your single logical line has to span multiple physical lines.