# Use 'in' to check is a word is part of an item in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

my code as follows:

```
a_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'this is a dog']

print('apple' in a_list)
-->>True

print('dog' in item for item in a_list)
-->><generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001E870D13F90>
```

Question:
Why do I get the <generator object  at 0x000001E870D13F90>?

How can I check, if 'dog' is in any item of this list, and the position of this item, i.e.,
'dog' is in the a_list[3]?

Thanks!

Comment: As to "Why do I get the generator", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164642/python-print-a-generator-expression .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use enumerate to get index and item at once.

```
for index, value in enumerate(a_list):
    if "dog" in value:
        print(index)
```

Comment: ^ This is the most efficient answer to me

Answer (score 2):

Using the predefined list , and a standard for loop, this should give you your expected answer:

```
a_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'this is a dog']
for i in a_list:
    if "dog" in i:
         print(a_list.index(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `any`, which checks through an iterator and returns `True` if any of them are try, else `False` (contrast with `all` which is only True if they are all True).

```py
print(any('dog' in item for item in a_list))
```

Comment: thanks, but is there is any possibility to get the id of the item which includes the 'dog'?

Comment: @Nina the `id` or the index in the list?

Comment: for example, 'dog' is in the a_list[3]