# Is there a way to make "print(l for l in List)" work?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

Hi

I am trying to shorten my code with some for loops inside of print functions, but I run into this problem:

```
List = ["######################",
        "#                    #",
        "#                    #",
        "#     Hello There    #",
        "#                    #",
        "#                    #",
        "######################"]

print(l for l in List)
```

Output:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001F704B0B820>
```

is there a way to make this work without doing:

```
for l in List:
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
######################
#                    #
#                    #
#     Hello There    #
#                    #
#                    #
######################
```

or do I have to stick with that?

I am sorry if this question is somewhere else, I just couldn't find it.
If you manage to find it, feel free to send a link instead of explaining it here too.

thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use a loop *inside* a `print`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing list elements on separated lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167731/printing-list-elements-on-separated-lines-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: print a generator expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164642/python-print-a-generator-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use loop inside `print()` but you can do

```
spam = ["######################",
        "#                    #",
        "#                    #",
        "#     Hello There    #",
        "#                    #",
        "#                    #",
        "######################"]
print('\n'.join(spam))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<generator>` message means your expression gets turned into a generator. You can turn a generator into a list, for example:

```py
print(list(l for l in List))
```

... or more generally by performing an operation which evaluates the generator until exhaustion and returns the result of the iteration.

Unfortunately, the output from the above is the output of `print(list(...)` without any formatting:

```
['######################', '#                    #', '#                    #', '#     Hello There    #', '#                    #', '#                    #', '######################']
```

Fortunately, you can *implicitly* perform the evaluation by passing the generator to `join`:

```py
print("\n".join(l for l in List))
```

... which of course is more simply expressed as

```py
print("\n".join(List))
```

Comment: really? list comprehension over a list object and then pass it to list() function????

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join method:

```
print("\n".join(List))
```

This is the easiest way you can do, `join(...)` takes an interable as a parameter so that you can pass a list, tuple, or a set. And then join all together using the delimiter that is `\n`.