# how do i extract integer values in fetching data from mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "select electricityBalance from users" 
mycursor.execute(sql)
print (int(record[0]) for record in mycursor.fetchone())
```

but the output gives this
<generator object  at 0x0000000002CFF2A0>

Comment: try using cursor.fetchall()

Answer (score 1):

[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164642/python-print-a-generator-expression), a generator expression is a "naked" `for` expression.

That is why you are getting `<generator object at 0x0000000002CFF2A0>`:

What you can do is this:

```
l1=[int(record[0]) for record in mycursor.fetchone()]
print(*l1)
```

Unpack a list.

You can also use `.join` method, but keep in mind that it requires elements which are **strings**.

```
print(','.join(str(int(record[0])) for record in mycursor.fetchone()))
```

Comment: it gave me an error saying that "int" object is not subscriptable

Comment: Which part? First or second @mostafakhalil

Comment: first, the sencond one gave me syntac error unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @mostafakhalil, check it now?

Comment: the second one gave me the first's proplem " int is not subscriptable both same proplem

Comment: ok i print the results normally it outputs exactly (9308.)
and when i tried to turn it into a float or integer it said 
the argument must be a string or number not a 'tuple' so thats the issue to begin with i think